# How can I do ADB backup without PC?

Tags: adb

I can backup with PC by "adb backup"command.
 But can I create backup file without using a PC somehow? 
Android device standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There are some tools to provide you with this functionality, e.g. [Helium - App Sync and Backup](http://de.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup). If your device is rooted, this app should work out-of-the-box. Otherwise you will need to initialize it once after each device start (reboot), which then requires a PC with ADB.

---

As requested in the comments, a few hints on how to get *Helium* started on a non-rooted device. First, this requires you to have at least a basic setup of ADB done on your computer (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)). Having met that, it should be as easy as enabling *USB-Debugging* on your Android device, connecting it via USB to the PC, and run the helper script downloaded from *Helum's* web page. The last 3 steps have to be repeated only once after each reboot of the device, and activate a background process *Helium* itself requires but cannot start itself (the user via ADB has higher privileges than an app in user-space, and thus can).

Comment: my device is not rooted.can helium do backup without pc?

Comment: Yes. If your device is not rooted, you only need a PC once after each restart/boot of your device to get a background service started (no "normal" app gets enough elevated rights for that, so ADB has to do). For the backups themselves you don't need any additional device, and they are done to your SDCard.

Comment: Izzy - Can you elaborate on how to initialize the program with ADB, after each restart?

Comment: That depends on your pre-conditions. But you're right, I should include some hints although they can be find on the app's page.